# how to run as another user

Tags: windows, tcl

I have written a generation server in Tcl which runs as a windows service.
When invoked, the generation server starts a new master process (sort of `make`), which will manage the generation by starting subprocesses:

```
server -> master -> program 1
                 -> program 2 ...
```

I want to limit write access of all processes below master to a single output directory only, while being able to read other sibling directories.

The solution I have in mind is to change the user of master process to a limited one (is it impersonation?), and let server create output directory and change owner and write attributes before and after the generation.

Is it possible with twapi? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Good question. No idea how to do this; I shall be watching with interest…

Comment: Impersonation would be the case if you used a thread, with an extra process you want `CreateProcessAsUser` or `CreateProcessWithLogon`.  See this page for some example with TWAPI (http://www.magicsplat.com/blog/playing-god/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll see how I can fit this to my needs.